# VS Code Output is returning the ... code... kind of :)

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

i get this weird quirks in VSCode (python and code runner)
print("ABC", "DEF", "XYZ") returns ('ABC', 'DEF', 'XYZ')
I'm expecting (ABC DEF XYZ)

Also print("ABC", "DEF", "XYZ", sep="!") returns a syntax error

Any help is of course more then appreciated :)

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: Are you running Python 2?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to replicate this exact behavior using Python 2.x

The reason is, you are using the syntax of the [`print()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.0.html#print-is-a-function) from Python 3.

The syntax for your commands using Python 2 `print` would be:

```
print "ABC", "DEF", "XYZ"
print "!".join(["ABC", "DEF", "XYZ"])
```

You could also try to import the back ported `print()` function to continue using the Python 3 syntax (would require a recent version of Python 2):

```
from __future__ import print_function
```

Comment: Thanks guys,
i'm using Python 3.9.6 (x64).

The .join worked perfectly :)
I'm still getting the parenthesis () and the apostrophe ' when outputing with the ()

So now i don't need the () anymore on the print function?

Comment: Ok, found this out :)

print("hello")
print ("hello", "hello")

Single argument doesnt output the () and the ' but multiple does

Comment: @DanielHurtubise. Has your question  been solved? I run your code both in terminal and output, get the same result `ABC DEF XYZ` and `ABC!DEF!XYZ`.

Comment: Yes and no @MollyWang-MSFT :)
I'm confused about this () or not

print("ABC", "DEF", "XYZ") returns ('ABC', 'DEF', 'XYZ')
print "ABC", "DEF", "XYZ" returns ABC DEF XYZ

Comment: @DanielHurtubise，Can you post a gif to show the execution process and result?

Comment: I recorded the screen here https://www.screencast.com/t/0dhphcF3x
Thanks for your patience :)

Comment: Ok, so some update
I installed Python 3.10.1 BUT ALSO added the path to the system environment (not just the user) and it's working fine now.
Thanks you everyone for your support